# Use default value product view backoffice magento

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, attributes, product-attribute

I have a problem in **magento 1.7** when I'm trying to check the **"use default value"** on a **product attribute**.

I would like to check  programmaticaly the checkbox **"use default value"** when the global **special_price** is the same as the **specific store special_price**.

My problem is all **"global values"** going to be empty when I used my script.

Thanks you if somebody can help me.

Cordially.

Here my script :

```
     $oGlobalProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(0)->load($iProductId);
        $oProduct = $oProductModel->setStoreId($iStoreId)->load($iProductId);
         //standard price is a custom attribute
        if($oGlobalProduct->getSpecialPrice() == $oProduct->getStandardPrice())
        {
             $setId = $oProduct->getAttributeSetId();

            $aAttribute = array();

            if ($setId)
            {
    // get all attribute group of the product
                $groupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection')
                    ->setAttributeSetFilter($setId)
                    ->setSortOrder()
                    ->load();

                foreach ($groupCollection as $group)
                {
                    $attributes = $oProduct->getAttributes($group->getId(), true);

                    foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute)
                    {
                        if (!$attribute->getIsVisible())
                        {
                            unset($attributes[$key]);
                        }
                        else {
                            $aAttribute[$attribute->getId()] = array(
                                'attribute_code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
                                'use_default' => $oProduct->getExistsStoreValueFlag($attribute->getAttributeCode()),
                                'global_value' => $oGlobalProduct->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()),
                                'store_value' => $oProduct->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode())
                            );
                        }
                        try{

                            if($aAttribute[$attribute->getId()]['global_value'] == $aAttribute[$attribute->getId()]['store_value'])
                            {
                                $oProduct->setStoreId($iStoreId)
                                    ->setData($attribute->getAttributeCode(), false);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e)
                        {
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $oProduct->save();
            }    
        }
```

Product view before the script (global) :

[image]

Product view before the script (store) :

[image]

Product view after the script (global)

[image]

Product view after the script (store)

[image]